# Android Studio после нажатия на кнопку вылетает

Tags: android

Создаю приложение на Android Studio, где задаю значение и диапазон, при нажатии на кнопку `button3` значения сохраняются в файл, при нажатии на `Button2` должно перейти на другую `Activity` и выдать мне график. При нажатии на кнопку вылетает. В чем может быть причина?

MainActivity

```
package com.example.lab_43;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        EditText B = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
        EditText F = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
        EditText T = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
        EditText S = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.step);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(B.getText().toString());
        double y = 3;
        double a = 8;
        double from = Double.parseDouble(F.getText().toString());
        double to = Double.parseDouble(T.getText().toString());
        double step = Double.parseDouble(S.getText().toString());
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("output.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            for (double i = from; i <= to; i += step) {
                double x = i;
                double res = (Math.sqrt(b + x - a) + Math.log(y)) / Math.atan(b + a);
                String X = String.format("%.3f", x);
                String result = String.format("%.3f", res);
                fileOutput.write(("X = " + X + " -> K = " + result + ";\n").getBytes());
            }
            fileOutput.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void onButtonClickFile(View v) {
        TextView data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("output.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuffer strbuff = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                strbuff.append(line.toString()).append("\n");
            }
            data.setText(strbuff.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void onButtonClickShowPlot(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.lab_43.Graphic");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Graphic

```
package com.example.lab_43;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Graphic extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphic);

        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("output.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String line;

            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                double[] numArr = Arrays.stream(line.split(" -> result = ")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(numArr[0], numArr[1]), true, 100);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        graph.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#CDDC39"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите b"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/from"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFC107"
        android:onClick="onButtonClickFile"
        android:text="Показать файл"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="189dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#8BC34A"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="От"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/step"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#8BC34A"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Шаг"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/to"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/to" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        android:onClick="onButtonClickShowPlot"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/step" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#8BC34A"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="К"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/from" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#CDDC39"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="Расчитать"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/step" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_graphic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Graphic">

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: logcat падения приложите https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: ну так и покажите нам Ваш LogCat!!! а вообще ставь BreakPoint и смотри,onButtonClickShowPlot(View v) и  как твоя новая активность создается onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  класс Graphic